# Filling Background Image on Screen

Tags: css

How can I make the background image size bigger where the silver portion will be under the whitebox in the center. Also there is a white gap between the black part and silver part in google chrome? How can I fix this?
Here's the site in action
http://www.andrewhnovak.com/test/index.html

```
body{ 
  background: url(../images/backgroundpic.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can set the width and height explicitly

Comment: Did you provide the wrong site link? I don't see any background img here.

Comment: That's weird the site link works for me. http://www.andrewhnovak.com/test/index.html  In this image you see the black footer under the white box. Maybe there's a better way to do this, but I definitely don't want the footer to be under there. Also there's the weird thing with the white gap between the silver and black in chrome as you can see in the pic

Comment: If you want to move the white box, you can adjust that by setting its `top` CSS attribute. `.whiteBox{top:80px;}`

Comment: I'm putting advertisements above the whiteBox so moving it isn't an option, So I want the background size larger so that it pushes the black part lower

Comment: There's a simple way to do that, assuming that the white box will always be at the center and has a fixed size, you can put your silver background on a <div> not on the <body> then use java script to get the screen height of the browser and set it as the height of the <div> the on your css use background-size: cover;

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/5mxwp39q/1/ try re-sizing the output window then click run to see the effect. Hope it helps you.